# Read multilingual data in R

Tags: r, string, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a dataset with more than 1 language (e.g. Korean, Chinese).

```
Country,Name
USA,Alix
Korea,티디
Germany,Zürn Gm
China,和  Taiwan
```

I have saved the file in csv format with UTF-8.

```
library(readr)
guess_encoding("test.csv", n_max = 1000)
  # A tibble: 1 x 2
  encoding confidence
  <chr>         <dbl>
  1 UTF-8             1
```

However, when I load the file into R, it is showing invalid character (<U+D2F0>):

```
df <- read.csv("test.csv",encoding = "UTF-8")
  Country             Name
  1     USA             Alix
  2   Korea <U+D2F0><U+B514>
  3 Germany          Zürn Gm
  4   China <U+548C>  Taiwan
```

How can I load and write the file to show the correct foreign characters?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to write the file as a .csv, you can consider saving it with `save()`, which will keep all formatting.